# WebForms Report Viewer JavaScript Error

Tags: c#, reporting-services, webforms, visual-studio-2017, reportviewer

I get javascript errors when adding a report to an ASPX page. When clicking the view button I get javascript errors.

A simple report with a set of parameters throws the following javascript error. I'm using the local processing mode with a dynamically generated set of data sources and parameters. When I load the page without parameters, I see the following error.
[image]

And when I add the parameters, the following exceptions will show up.
[image]

This is the code to generate the report. The backend processing runs successfully, but when it comes to the client-side processing, it fails to display the report component.

```
ReportViewer1.Reset();
ReportViewer1.Visible = true;
ReportViewer1.EnableTelemetry = false;
ReportViewer1.ShowParameterPrompts = true;
ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath($"~/Reports/{_reportName}");

foreach (var param in ReportParameters.Where(r => r.Hidden))
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter(param.Name, param.DefaultValue));

foreach (var dataset in DataSets)
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource(dataset, GetReportData(dataset)));

ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

Update:
I just noticed this issue only happens in Chrome. I've been able to open the report in IE successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this issue happens when a previous version of SSRS still cached in the IIS Express or IIS. A system restart resolved the issue.